# Python Radix Sort

Tags: python, radix-sort

I'm trying to implement Radix sort in python.

My current program is not working correctly in that a list like [41,51,2,3,123] will be sorted correctly to [2,3,41,51,123], but something like [52,41,51,42,23] will become [23,41,42,52,51] (52 and 51 are in the wrong place).

I think I know why this is happening, because when I compare the digits in the tens place, I don't compare units as well (same for higher powers of 10).

How do I fix this issue so that my program runs in the fastest way possible? Thanks!

```
def radixsort(aList):
    BASEMOD = 10
    terminateLoop = False
    temp = 0
    power = 0
    newList = []
    while not terminateLoop:
        terminateLoop = True
        tempnums = [[] for x in range(BASEMOD)]

        for x in aList:
            temp = int(x / (BASEMOD ** power))
            tempnums[temp % BASEMOD].append(x)
            if terminateLoop:
                terminateLoop = False


        for y in tempnums:
            for x in range(len(y)):
                if int(y[x] / (BASEMOD ** (power+1))) == 0:
                     newList.append(y[x])
                     aList.remove(y[x])



        power += 1

    return newList

print(radixsort([1,4,1,5,5,6,12,52,1,5,51,2,21,415,12,51,2,51,2]))
```

Comment: If you cared about speed you wouldn't create your own sort.

Comment: I'm trying to make the fastest sort I can

Comment: Basically, I don't want it to be O(n^2) or something

Comment: Just to clarify, you realize you won't end up with a sort faster than the builtin one, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm not a stickler for speed, but I want it to be approximately the normal time for a radix program.

Comment: Time is not of importance really, I am more looking for an efficient algorithm

Comment: Recently another question was about the [fastest sorting algorithms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317442/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-faster-than-quicksort) (but based on ``np.ndarray``). Maybe this will help.

Comment: My aim is to learn and understand how to write a good radix, not get one for other purposes

Answer (score 2):

Currently, your sort does nothing to reorder values based on anything but their highest digit. You get `41` and `42` right only by chance (since they are in the correct relative order in the initial list).

You should be always build a new list based on each cycle of the sort.

```
def radix_sort(nums, base=10):
    result_list = []
    power = 0
    while nums:
        bins = [[] for _ in range(base)]
        for x in nums:
            bins[x // base**power % base].append(x)
        nums = []
        for bin in bins:
            for x in bin:
                if x < base**(power+1):
                    result_list.append(x)
                else:
                    nums.append(x)
         power += 1
     return result_list
```

Note that radix sort is not necessarily faster than a comparison-based sort. It only has a lower complexity if the number of items to be sorted is larger than the range of the item's values. Its complexity is `O(len(nums) * log(max(nums)))` rather than `O(len(nums) * log(len(nums)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Radix sort sorts the elements by first grouping the individual digits of the same place value. [2,3,41,51,123] first we group them based on first digits.

```
[[],[41,51],[2],[3,123],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

Then, sort the elements according to their increasing/decreasing order. new array will be

```
[41,51,2,3,123]
```

then we will be sorting based on tenth digit. in this case [2,3]=[02,03]

```
[[2,3],[],[123],[],[41],[51],[],[],[],[]]
```

now new array will be

```
    [2,3,123,41,51]
```

lastly based on 100th digits. this time [2,3,41,51]=[002,003,041,051]

```
  [[2,3,41,51],[123],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

finally we end up having [2,3,41,51,123]

```
def radixsort(A):
    if not isinstance(A,list):
        raise TypeError('')
    n=len(A)
    maxelement=max(A)
    digits=len(str(maxelement)) # how many digits in the maxelement
    l=[]
    bins=[l]*10 # [[],[],.........[]] 10 bins
    for i in range(digits):
        for j in range(n): #withing this we traverse unsorted array
            e=int((A[j]/pow(10,i))%10)
            if len(bins[e])>0:
                bins[e].append(A[j]) #adds item to the end
            else:
                bins[e]=[A[j]]
        k=0 # used for the index of resorted arrayA
        for x in range(10):#we traverse the bins and sort the array 
            if len(bins[x])>0:
                for y in range(len(bins[x])):
                    A[k]=bins[x].pop(0) #remove element from the beginning
                    k=k+1
```